# Shell - How can I bring Logrotate to wait until file is copied/written and than go on

Tags: shell, loops, logrotate

I have a big logfile that is copied by cron to /var/log/ every hour. Some minutes later logrote start the work with zipping and rename.

My problem is, that the copy process is not already finished. The result is, the copied logfile and archieve are corrupt.

So what I want, is a shell-script that takes a look befor on the copied file and check is it in use.

```
#!/bin/bash
until err_str=$(lsof /var/log/logfile.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null); do
  if [ -n "$err_str" ]; then
    # lsof printed an error string, file may or may not be open
    echo "lsof: $err_str" >&2

    # tricky to decide what to do here, you may want to retry a number of times,
    # but for this example just break
    break
  fi

  # lsof returned 1 but didn't print an error string, assume the file is open
  sleep 1
done
```

This is not working, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Well, won't err_str be always with nothing in it ? You are redirecting everything to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using-

while err_str=$(lsof /var/log/logfile.txt 2>/dev/null); do
  if [ -z "$err_str" ]; then